# Match something like its previous occurrence

Tags: php, regex, match

I need to make a regex which matches content between tags like this:

```
<tag>
    <b> Match Me </b>
</other-closing-tag>
```

It should match only the content between the same tag. So the result should be something like this:

```
1 match:
<b> Match Me </b>
Match me
```

And I need to do it in PHP, but I don't think that this is that important...

Comment: If you're trying to parse HTML, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Toomai Not exactly html but an html-like structure. Anyway thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression back references, which you can read more about under the following link.

- [PHP: Back references - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php)

Though parsing html with regular-expressions is never a good idea, but I'm going to pretend that you are going to use this information for a completely different problem. ;-)

---

#### Example snippet

In the below we are saying that the contents of our end-tag should be the same as what is matched by our first group `([^>]+)`, by using `\1` inside our closing tag.

```
$data =<<<EOT
  <awesome-tag> match-me </awesome-tag>
  <error-tag>   match-me </err0r-tag>
  <super-tag>   match-me </super-tag>
  <error-tag>   match-me </err0r-tag>
  <awesome-tag> match-me </awesome-tag>
EOT;

preg_match_all ('/<([^>]+)>.*?match-me.*?<\/\1>/s', $data, $matches);

print_r ($matches);
```

output

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => <awesome-tag> match-me </awesome-tag>
    [1] => <super-tag>   match-me </super-tag>
    [2] => <awesome-tag> match-me </awesome-tag>
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [0] => awesome-tag
    [1] => super-tag
    [2] => awesome-tag
  )
)
```

Comment: This looks good, easy, clean... basically an elegant solution. I'll try it.
Thanks

Comment: This is the BEST solution I have ever received in StackOverflow!

Comment: I always try my best to write elaborate answers that will satisfy OP and aid future users finding the question through searching. Thank you.